# Excel Cell ref Failed

Tags: excel

Update : [sheets example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dI3Jeln_rw42wUKhPe-UMTLQWwoh2bCg/view?usp=sharing) notice the DP9 row.

I have sheet1 for Salary calculation. looks like:

```
Sheet1
  A            B      C
1 DepartmentA Jason 1000
2 DepartmentA Bill  1000
3 DepartmentA Joe   1000
4 DepartmentA Total 3000       \\Formula =SUM(C1:C3)
5 DepartmentB Ken   1500
6 DepartmentB Marry 1500
7 DepartmentB Maria 1500
8 DepartmentB Total 4500       \\Formula =SUM(C5:C7)
```

I want summary without details in sheet2 like :

```
Sheet2
  A            B         C
1 DepartmentA Total =SUM(C1:C3)
2 DepartmentB Total =SUM(C5:C7)
```

So i Copied the lines with total , right clicked and Paste link.
I expected to see :

```
Sheet1 
  A            B      C
1 DepartmentA Total 3000
2 DepartmentB Total 4500
```

But instead saw :

```
Sheet2
  A            B      C
1 DepartmentA Total 3000
2 DepartmentB Total 0
```

I was confusing so i copied the cell C2 and choose Paste Link to D2 in same sheet,then I got :

```
Sheet2
  A            B      C    D
1 DepartmentA Total 3000
2 DepartmentB Total 4500   -
```

I'm so confused now .

Comment: Why not use a `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: can you share the sheet

Comment: @Ranga example sheet. uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh dear,  this is very simple issue. you have a circular loop error on row 46 column D, E, F and G. if you check the formula of these cells you will find that its adding itself and cells below them.

correct formula for below cells to

D46

```
=SUM(D29:D45)
```

E46

```
=SUM(E29:E45)-E50
```

F46

```
=SUM(F29:F45)-F50
```

G46

```
=SUM(G29:G45)-G50
```

H46

```
=SUM(H29:H45)-H50
```

to remove and check any other circular loops goto Excel Tab
Formulas-> Error checking -> Circular references

After this you can easily copy/paste with links and this will get all the values correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you data looks like below in `Sheet1` then use `SUMIFS()`.

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,A1)
```

[image]

If data looks like this
[image]

Then use filter formula with `Excel365`.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:C8,Sheet1!B1:B8="Total")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips , but is it possible to solve it without changing the sheet1?
Because I have many files to deal with.
I've uploaded the example sheet.